# ASP.net FileUpload change current location dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, file, upload

Basically I have an edit feature where I can load a record and I can edit its contents. Part of what I can edit is the Image which I'm using a FileUpload for. When I select a record, the textboxes are filled with the CURRENT data and the user can edit each of them accordingly. How can I change what is currently written in the FileUpload by extracting the string of the ImageURL from the database?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the prerender event of the fileUpload class to modify the object properties before rendering
see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.prerender%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)